# Can't get my pages translated without changing `settings.LANGUAGE_CODE' in Django

Tags: django, internationalization

I'm trying to implement internationalization on my project, but the pages only get translated with the language from `settings.LANGUAGE_CODE`.

The value of `django_language` in the user session is correctly set, so is the request header `META[HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE]`, but the templates are still rendered with the value in `LANGUAGE_CODE`.

I must use `translation.activate(request.session['django_language'])` in my views to get the pages translated in the right language.

Is there a way to translate the pages *without* using `translation.activate` ?

For information :

- The desired language to translate to is `pt-br`, which is in the default `LANGUAGES` set.
- If I set `pt-br` to the `LANGUAGE_CODE` the pages are translated.
- The default language must be `en-us`.
- My *locale* directory is on the project root.

The locale variables on my `settings.py` :

```
LOCALEURL_USE_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE = True

LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'locale/'),
    os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, '/'),
) 

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    "django.core.context_processors.i18n", 
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
)

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',    
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send `RequestContext` as your `context_instance` from your views :

```
return render_to_response('hello.html',
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```